# Solr query response contains non-utf-8 characters

Tags: php, curl, encoding, solr, utf-8

I am indexing French text in Solr running on Fedora 20 with Tomcat 7. I have tried both solr 4.8.1 and 4.9.0. The problem is that the title_fr field is coming back from query in some strange encoding.

The indexing and retrieval are done from PHP using the builtin curl. The index requests use "extract" and pass in some extra fields - this a dump of the POST array given to PHP curl.

```
[literal.id] => cdddd
[uprefix] => attr_
[fmap.content] => text_fr
[literal.title] =>  Québec laisse tomber 
[commit] => true
[myfile] => CURLFile Object ( 
    [name] => /tmp/cccz6GT4n
    [mime] => text/html
    [postname] => cccz6GT4n
)
[literal.url] => /features
[literal.type_s] => content
[literal.extractFormat] => text
[literal.id_s] => chapZrZqYJcEcG
[literal.title_fr] =>  Québec laisse tomber 
[literal.lang_s] => fr
```

This generates a multipart-mime POST to Solr. I have confirmed that the encoding of all the parts is UTF-8.

The problem is that when results are returned from a query, the title_fr field is strangely encoded. The JSON response string is (this happens for XML as well; note that I have added a couple carriage returns to make the interesting bits visible without scrolling)

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":7,"params":{"hl.fragsize":"500","hl.mergeContinuous":"true","fl":"id,score,title,id_s,title_fr,title_en","sort":"","hl.snippets":"500","q":"text_fr:Québec title_fr:Québec","hl.fl":"text_en,text_fr,title_en,title_fr","wt":"json","hl":"true","rows":"10000"}},"response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"maxScore":0.1354348,"docs":[{"id":"cddd",
"title_fr":[" QuÃ©bec laisse tomber "],"id_s":"cddd","score":0.1354348}]},
"highlighting":{"cddd":{"text_fr":[" \n \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n \n \n<em>Québec</em>  téléphone\nLe conflit à Gaza plombe  \nà Gaza a"]}}}
```

The second line shows where title_fr is returned - it appears in my editor as if it were encoded with ISO-8859-1, but PHP's `iconv('iso8859-1', 'utf-8'. ...)` simply doubles up the funny characters. The third line shows the highlights from the text_fr reasonably encoded.

The schema.xml uses a wild card

```
   <dynamicField name="*_fr"  type="text_fr"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

which should cover both text_fr and title_fr.

I suspect that Solr extract is not treating the characters in the POST as UTF-8 -- the funny characters show up in all of the response formats for queries made from the admin interface.

I have fixed the connector for Tomcat in server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

though I have been told it is no longer necessary for Solr.

If this is the case, queries are not going to match the title.

If there is nothing to force extract to treat the encoding correctly, does anyone know of a PHP call that would turn the title_fr string back into UTF-8? I have tried several that I found in internet searches involving `pack` and `preg_replace_callback` but nothing seems to be making sense of the returned string.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're double encoding the array before submitting it to Solr. The string you're getting back is at least your string encoded twice, where it's first converted to `utf-8`, then converted to `utf-8` again (this time assuming it is `iso-8859-1`, while it is `utf-8`).

So your hunch is right, but you've got your encodings backwards.

```
$ php -r 'print(iconv("utf-8", "iso-8859-1", "QuÃ©bec laisse tomber"));'
Québec laisse tomber
```

It's impossible to say where you end up doing the double encode, but it's somewhere outside of the code you've included. You can use `ngrep` or `wireshark` to see the actual byte encoding being submitted to the server, if you still suspect it happens after it leaves your application.